# R - Converting multiple dataframes within a list to numeric

Tags: r, list, nested, type-conversion, categorical-data

I´ve recreated the datastructure so it may help me to get my question better across. Lets generate some data.

```
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
b <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
c <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
d <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
df1 <- data.frame(as.factor(a),as.factor(b),as.factor(c),as.factor(d))

b <- c(10,20,30,40)
d <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
a <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
c <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
df2 <- data.frame(as.factor(a),as.factor(b),as.factor(c),as.factor(d))

df<-list(df1,df2)
```

Let´s suppose i only got `df`. I need to change all the entries of `df1` and `df2` within `df` from a factor/categorical data to numeric while preserving the structure of two dataframes within a list.

Thanks for your help!
Best regards
Kevin

Comment: I´ve reframed the question and added data, sorry for the bad explanation beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to `map` a function across the two data frames. This is super easy with `type_convert`. All you need to do is convert everything to character first and then let type_convert figure out what should be what. Note that I made the data a `tibble` first only so you could see the data type printed here.

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(df, ~as_tibble(.x) |>
      mutate(.x, across(everything(), as.character)) |> 
      type_convert())
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   a = col_double(),
#>   b = col_character(),
#>   c = col_logical(),
#>   d = col_double()
#> )
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   a = col_logical(),
#>   b = col_double(),
#>   c = col_double(),
#>   d = col_character()
#> )
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a b           c         d
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <lgl> <dbl>
#> 1    10 book        TRUE    2.5
#> 2    20 pen         FALSE   8  
#> 3    30 textbook    TRUE   10  
#> 4    40 pencil_case FALSE   7  
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   a         b     c d          
#>   <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 TRUE     10   2.5 book       
#> 2 FALSE    20   8   pen        
#> 3 TRUE     30  10   textbook   
#> 4 FALSE    40   7   pencil_case
```

EDIT

If you want things as integers, the process is exactly the same. You are essentially converting the variables to numberic based on their factor levels:

```r
map(df, ~as_tibble(.x) |>
      mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a     b     c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     2     1
#> 2     2     2     1     3
#> 3     3     4     2     4
#> 4     4     3     1     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>       a     b     c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     3     2
#> 3     2     3     4     4
#> 4     1     4     2     3
```

Comment: Sorry but I think that´s not what I´m looking for. Let´s take the TRUE/FALSE column for example. It needs to be converted to integers. Same goes for the book, pen,... column. Every factor needs to be assigned an integer. I can do exactly what I want for `df1` and `df2 `independently using `df1[sapply(df1, is.factor)] <- data.matrix(df1[sapply(df1, is.factor)])` I pretty much need this solution but applied to the list where `df1` and `df2` are inside `df`.

Comment: So you want to convert the variables to their factor levels? is my edit what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks your code worked almost, Had to adjust it a litte cause of the way my data is structured. Nothing you could tested yourself. Solution was: `df <-   map(df, ~as_tibble(.x) |>
#                  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)))`